# Google analytics iOS encoding issue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, google-analytics

I'm trying to log events on my app via Google Analytics. I decided that I want these events to be logged in JSON format for easy processing later on, so there is a need for logging event categories such as

```
{gameplay:'idByName'}
```

and event labels such as:

```
{o:['838','851','793','843'], g:[1], t:'6'}
```

The meaning of the data is irrelevant, but what's important is that I see these strings fine on my console before reporting them to Google and when I view them in my analytics dashboard (sadly, 24 hours later) I get buggy strings such as:

```
{gameplay:idByName}
```

or

```
{o:[64,*14,)3,800], g:[1], t:!}
```

Right now I am unable to verify which label on the console belongs to which label on the analytics dashboard, but what can be understood from this is that the characters are being corrupted for some reason. Also, I am using the

```
\'
```

format for defining a single apostrophe in an NSString.
Any ideas as to why this is happening will be gladly accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly obvious that the JSON is possible (the object structure is preserved) and that numeric data doesn't cause an issue because `g:[1]` is correctly reported.

So the issue is with your single-quotes. It's likely that Google's processing uses single-quotes and maybe backslashes as well.

I would first try double-quotes for your string values, and you may need to escape them with backslashes too. Try a mixture of delimiters

```
 {o:[\'838\',\"851\","793",'843'], g:[1], t:'6'}
```

and see which arrive correctly in the results.

Comment: Thanks, I'll perform this check

Comment: Seems as though only double quotes behave well. I'm going to try and wait for an answer that will let me use the ' character but if I see it's not possible, I'll give you a tick. Thanks again, Andrew

Comment: @stavash: You may be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133713/json-is-not-valid which asserts that double-quotes are the only valid option.

Comment: I'm also used to working with double quotes, it was a client's request. I'll see if this suffices.