# Not sure why this JSON is invalid

Tags: json

Can anyone tell me why this JSON is invalid?

```
{ NetworkOrgID :8 {{'NetworkOrgName':'Network Org'},{'FacilityName':'ACN Clinic ID'},{'City':'ChangedFlag'},{'FacilityName':'ClinicName'},{'PhoneNumber':'Address 1'},{'FaxNumber':'City'},{'MedicalServiceCode':'State'},{'FacilitySpecialties':'Zip'}}}
```

running it through a validator I get:

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    'NetworkOrgID': '8'{
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

Comment: `NetworkOrgID` must be in quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON is not valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133713/json-is-not-valid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your JSON. Firstly, all property names must be surrounded by double-quotes (`"`):

```
{ Foo : "bar" }   // Invalid
{ "Foo" : "bar" } // Valid
```

Secondly, string values must be surrounded by double-quotes (`"`), not single-quotes (`'`).

```
{ "Foo" : 'bar' } // Invalid
{ "Foo" : "bar" } // Valid
```

That aside, there are more serious problems with your JSON. I'm going to reformat it to make it easier to read, and add some line numbers to make it easier to talk about:

```
 1 | {
 2 |   "NetworkOrgID": 8
 3 |   {
 4 |     { "NetworkOrgName": "Network Org" },
 5 |     { "FacilityName": "ACN Clinic ID" },
 6 |     { "City": "ChangedFlag" },
 … |     …
12 |   }
13 | }
```

Even having fixed the quotation marks, this data structure doesn't make any sense. In JSON, curly braces indicate an object. An object consists of name/value pairs:

```
{ "Foo": 1,
  "Bar": 2,
  "Baz": 3
}
```

The above is an object with three property names, `"Foo"`, `"Bar"`, and `"Baz"`, with the values `1`, `2`, and `3` respectively. Note that each value except the last is followed by a comma (`,`), except the last.

In your code you have an object (which begins on line 1), followed by one name/value pair (`"NetworkOrgID": 8`) on line 2. So far, so good. But then on line 3 you have another opening curly brace (`{`)—but you can't do that here. Remember, an object consists of name/value pairs. You can't put an object inside another object without giving it a property name, e.g.:

```
{
  "NetworkOrgID": 8,
  "NestedObject": {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Next, on lines 4–11 you have a series of objects separated by commas. Each object has a single name/value pair. It seems like you may have intended this to be an array, which goes in square brackets, not curly braces:

```
[
  { "NetworkOrgName": "Network Org" },
  { "FacilityName": "ACN Clinic ID" },
  { "City": "ChangedFlag" },
  // ...
]
```

And, as I said before, you can only put this inside another object if it's the value in a name/value pair. This is valid JSON:

```
{
  "NetworkOrgID": 8
  "MyArray": [
    { "NetworkOrgName": "Network Org" },
    { "FacilityName": "ACN Clinic ID" },
    { "City": "ChangedFlag" },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

If you were to deserialize this to JavaScript with e.g. `var obj = JSON.parse(json);`, then the value of `obj.NetworkOrgID` would be `8` and the value of `obj.MyArray` would be the array of objects, so `obj.MyArray[0]` would be the object `{ "NetworkOrgName": "Network Org" }`, `obj.MyArray[1]` would be `{ "FacilityName": "ACN Clinic ID" }`, and so on.

Obviously you should come up with a better name than `"MyArray"` for that property.

Comment: Thanks. I thought ' and " were interchangeable.

Comment: Single- and double-quotes are interchangeable in JavaScript, but *JSON is not JavaScript*. JSON is a subset of JavaScript. I highly recommend taking a few moments to read the JSON documentation: http://www.json.org/ It's *very* brief and will help you avoid these problems in the future.

Answer (score -1):

This would be valid:

```
 { "NetworkOrgID": 8,
"NetworkOrgName": "NetworkOrg",
"FacilityName": "ACNClinicID" .... }
```